# How to connect to Visual Studio server remotely?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, remote-access, remote-server, ports

On my desktop I have Visual Studio 2013 installed and use it for web development. I want to be able to access to view the pages I created on other systems on the same network (iMac, tablet, phone) but I can't seem to be able to do this.

I've tried the following:

1. Installed SPI Port Forward and tried to change the ports. However, when browsing the file remotely in a browser (192.168.0.5:8081/rate.aspx), I get the following error message: Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
   HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.
2. I've also tried the suggestion posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22106287/2903635 but that doesn't seem to work.

Any possible solutions?

Comment: Can you use IIS instead of IISExpress? IIS supports non-local connections.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: @epalm Yes, the problem was resolved by reinstalling Visual Studio and IIS. Shall I delete the question?